# All GA4 Events After a specific event fires in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I use Looker Studio to show Google Analytics 4 data for some of my clients that I work with. We fire multiple events on their website for when consumers submit a form, click to call, etc. We also fire an event that is called "recent_consumer" which is fired at the beginning of any session where our pixel identifies we know that consumer.

I am trying to build a Scorecard in Looker of all attributed Form Fills, Click to Call events that:

1. Come from a specific source / medium (123.com for example) -- this is easy
2. Any form events that occur after that "recent_consumer" event fires within the same session

#2 is what I cannot seem to figure out. I tried to do a filter on the score card that was:
include session source equal to abc.com
OR
include Event Name containing recent_consumer

But that doesn't work, obviously since GA4 is all event based. So I am hoping to find a way I can do a funnel of some sort, IF recent_consumer fires, include all events AFTER that fires in the same session... But I can't figure that out.

[GA4 Filter Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltMM2.png)

My attempt:
include session source equal to abc.com
OR
include Event Name containing recent_consumer